# How to get raw query image url in Django?

Tags: sql, django

I am trying to get the URL of an image by raw queries results.
Tell how I can get the image URL by image name.

```py
cursor.execute(f"select p.id,p.name,p.price,p.sale_price,p.img,c.category from product_product p inner join product_category c on p.category_id=c.id order by p.id desc")
```

How can I get the absolute URL of p.img?

Comment: Why do you use raw queries over Django's ORM?

Comment: I was stucking using ORM

Comment: Have you any idea regarding my problem.?

Comment: The above looks like `Product.objects.select_related('category')`

Comment: I had used complex queries than this .

Comment: Its very dificult to handle using ORM . I am gone very deep into project that i started.

Comment: usually if the ORM is hard, it is not the ORM, it is the modelling that is wrong...

Comment: Is there any methods that returns the image url by taking image name?

Comment: the URL is not part of the database, Django's `ImageField` magic converts that. This is *one* of the many reasons why using an ORM is a good idea: Django wraps a lot of values between the database and Python, sometimes with a lot of hidden logic.

Comment: Is it possible to store image URL in database on uploading image ?